# ensuring data-consistency of object

Tags: boost-python

I'm having a problem with data-consistencies of objects e.g. how to deal with objects that get deleted while the user still has a reference to them.

simple pseudo-code example

```
node = graph.getNode(name)

node.destroy() < -- node gets destroyed
#or
graph.destroyNode(name)

node.getName() #<-- should complain that we're trying to reference an object that does not exist any more
```

a simple pseudo-code example would be

```
struct Node
{
   /*...*/
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;

struct Graph
{
   std::map<std::string,NodePtr> nodeMap;

   NodePtr getNode(std::string name);
   void removeNode(std::string name);  
   /*...*/
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Graph> GraphPtr;

// wrapper arround the the getNode function
object Graph_getNode( object obj, const std::string& key )
{
     GraphPtr graphPtr = extract< GraphPtr >(obj);
     return boost::python::api::object(graphPtr->getNode(key));
};

class_< Node,boost::noncopyable, NodePtr >( "Node", "node", no_init )
    /*....*/

class_< Graph, bases<Node>, boost::noncopyable, GraphPtr >( "Graph", "graph", no_init )
    .def("getNode", Graph_getNode, "get a node if it exists")
    /*....*/
```

Are there any functions that I could define which are run on a Node-object every time it gets used where I could check if it is still valid ?

I hope this information is sufficient to understand my problem,
 ... thanks for reading!

Seb

Answer (score 0):

As `Node` is exposed as being held by a `boost::shared_ptr`, the instance's lifetime can be affected by both C++ and Python.  Python will keep the C++ `Node` object alive as long as a handle to the Python object holding the `boost::shared_ptr` exists.

Therefore, in the following code, lets start with the precondition that a `Node` named `spam` is held in `graph`.  The code is annotated with the reference count for the C++ `Node` instance, as well as the Python `Node` instance.

```python
# The node named 'spam' is held in
# graph's nodeMap.
# cpp count: 1; python count: 0

# Boost.Python creats a Python Node object
# that holds boost::shared_ptr<Node>.
node = graph.getNode('spam') # cpp count: 2; python count: 1

# Removes the boost::shared_ptr<Node> for
# 'spam' from graph.nodeMap.
graph.destroyNode('spam') # cpp count: 1; python count: 1

# The C++ Node is still alive because the
# Python Node holds a boost::shared_ptr<Node>
node.getName() # cpp count: 1; python count: 1

# When Python no longer has a handle to the
# Python Node object, it will be garbage
# collected, which in turn will destroy
# the held boost::shared_ptr<Node>
node = None # cpp count: 0; python count: 0
```

If `node.getName()` should not operate successfully on a destroyed `node`, then consider explicitly managing state.  For example, `node.destroy()` would set state within `node`, and member-functions would check state before performing operations.  If the state indicates the `node` has been destroyed, then raise an exception or handle it appropriately.

---

Here is a basic example demonstrating the lifetime:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Node
{
public:
  Node(std::string name)
    : name_(name)
  {
    std::cout << "Node()" << std::endl;
  }

  ~Node()
  {
    std::cout << "~Node()" << std::endl;
  }

  std::string name() { return name_; }

private:
  std::string name_;
};

class Graph
{
public:
  // @brief Add node by name.
  void add_node(std::string name)
  {
    nodes_.insert(make_pair(name, boost::make_shared<Node>(name)));
  }

  /// @brief Destroy node by name.
  void destroy_node(std::string name)
  {
    nodes_.erase(name);
  }

  // @brief Get node by name.
  boost::shared_ptr<Node> get_node(std::string name)
  {
    nodes_type::iterator result = nodes_.find(name);
    return (result != nodes_.end())
      ? result->second
      : boost::shared_ptr<Node>();
  }

private:
  typedef std::map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<Node> > nodes_type;
  nodes_type nodes_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  python::class_<Node, boost::shared_ptr<Node>, 
      boost::noncopyable>("Node", python::no_init)
    .def("name", &Node::name)
    ;

  python::class_<Graph, boost::noncopyable>("Graph")
    .def("add_node",     &Graph::add_node)
    .def("get_node",     &Graph::get_node)
    .def("destroy_node", &Graph::destroy_node)
    ;
}
```

And its usage in Python:

```python
>>> from example import Graph
>>> graph = Graph()
>>> graph.add_node('spam')
Node()
>>> node = graph.get_node('spam')
>>> print node.name()
spam
>>> graph.destroy_node('spam')
>>> print node.name()
spam
>>> graph = None
>>> node = None
~Node()
```

Note how `Node`'s destructor was only invoked once Python no longer had a handle to the object.